# How to click on the "Mail" button on the yahoo page using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I got a **BUTTON** variable for those buttons:

```
GoMailsBTN = browser.find_element_by_class_name("D(ib) Fz(14px) Fw(b) Lh(24px) Pstart(38px)")
GoMailsBTN.click()
```

and there is not like any id you can go check it out by yourself if you want!
This is the **error** that pops out
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
Anyone got any idea why this is?

Snapshot of the button:

[image: html]

Comment: Post the HTML of the button in your answer so we can create a locator. ... and the problem is that the string you are passing is not a valid class name. There are no spaces in a valid class name... and probably not parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

The class name is dynamic and can change, in this case, you can use xpath:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li//a[contains(@href ,'mail') and not(@id)]")
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://in.yahoo.com/?p=us')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#header-mail-button span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://in.yahoo.com/?p=us')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='header-mail-button']//span"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: yahoomail]